# Installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 Built-In display appear as Unknown Display

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I dual-boot installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 (LTS) on a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 (AMD version), when trying to connect to a 2nd monitor and checking Displays, it says Unknown Device, executing xrandr gives the following output:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080 default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1920x1080 0.0*

HDMI and monitor work properly on Windows 10, also tried to install in another laptop (Acer Swift 3, Intel Graphics), and it detected both displays by default. So i think it might be problem of AMD drivers or something.

Comment: Current Kernel is: 5.4.0-53-generic